# Correct definition of constants

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables

I'm having a little trouble defining the constants I use in my code in a correct way. Although I read the excellent post  Jonathan Leffler over at [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c), I seem to have misunderstood something. This is the setup:

```
/*   constants.h   */
extern int NUM_PARTICLES;
extern int LIGHTSPEED;
```

This header is used in [random.h](http://pastebin.com/STmL2WWj) and [main.c](http://pastebin.com/UdVf08xs), which looks like

```
#include "constants.h"
int NUM_PARTICLES=104;
```

in `random.h` or

```
#include "constants.h"
int LIGHTSPEED=104;
```

in `main.c`, respectively. `NUM_PARTICLES` is used in main.c in

```
30:  double ghosts[NUM_PARTICLES][4];
31:  double output[NUM_PARTICLES][3];
```

Although this thing works, I get the following warnings,

```
main.c: In function ‘int main()’:
main.c:30:32: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘ghosts’ [-Wvla]
main.c:31:32: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘output’ [-Wvla]
```

which is weird, because in my opinion I **do** give the array a constant value that is known at compilation time. (And usually these array length errors cause some segfaults, which in this case they do not.) Any ideas?

Comment: In addition to your problem as such, you have the problem that you are compiling C code as C++, which isn't a good idea. In particular the handling of `const` qualified variables is different between the two.

Comment: Yeah, I had that sneaky feeling that mixing C with C++ would cause some problems, but unfortunately I can't change it ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short story: this is a quirk of C.

Normally, you would define an integer constant as

```
const int LIGHTSPEED = 104;
```

The problem is that according to the language rules this constant is not a *constant expression*, and thus cannot be used to specify the size of a statically allocated array.

The relevant part of the C standard (6.6/6, I am not making this up) defines what an *integer constant expression* is:

> An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall
>   only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
>   character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
>   constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of
>   casts.

There are two solutions for this. The classic one is to use a macro, which simply pastes `104` between the angle brackets before the compiler sees the code, therefore making the array size an integer constant:

```
#define NUM_PARTICLES 104
```

The better one (IMO) is to avoid a macro because you can, and use an `enum`, which is possible (you are using an enumeration constant):

```
enum { NUM_PARTICLES = 104 };
```